# Use a batch script as ConEmu task

Tags: windows, batch-file, conemu, cmder

I frequently need to connect to various servers using SSH. I use the built-in SSH client from [Cmder](http://cmder.net/), like that :

```
cmd /c "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe root@server1" -new_console:C:"C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico" -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:server1
```

But I'm lazy, hence I want to write a batch script that will take just one argument to connect to any SSH endpoint (eg: `conssh root@server1`), and will be called to create new ConEmu tabs from the [*New console* dialog](http://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html) (creating as many ConEmu tasks as server is not an option).

**conssh.bat** (within %PATH%) :

```
@echo off

:: Aliases
if "%1"=="s1" (
    set arg="root@server1"
) else if "%1"=="c1" (
    set arg="-t root@server1 ssh root@container1.lxc"
) else (
    set arg=%1
)

:: cmd /c "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -new_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail (works, but opens a useless tab : "ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=121.")

:: cmd /c "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -cur_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -cur_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -cur_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail (ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.)

:: "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -new_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail (ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.)

:: cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -new_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail (works, but opens a useless tab : "ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=121.")

:: cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -cur_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -cur_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -cur_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail (opens a cmd.exe shell, not ssh)

:: cmd /c -new_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:"%1"
:: cmd /c "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%"
:: => Fail (opens a useless tab, with wrong icon)

:: start /b "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -new_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail

:: start /b "%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -cur_console:C:C:\Apps\cmder-git\icons\cmder.ico -cur_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -cur_console:t:"%1"
:: => Fail
```

How can I make it works (open only one tab, with the right icon, palette and title) ?

Thanks

Comment: Where Gabe you installed ConEmu? Try first variant with -new_console, but use `ConEmuC.exe -c` instead of `cmd /c`.

Comment: I got the same result with `ConEmuC.exe -c ...` : useless tab with ExitCode=121. I use `ConEmuC build 160710 x86` on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, found a workaround using `ConEmu -Single` (the script is run directly from the windows shell instead of the *New console dialog*) :

```
@echo off

set cmderlocation=C:\Apps\cmder-git
set icon=cmder_blue.ico

:: Aliases
if "%1"=="s1" (
    set arg=root@server1
) else if "%1"=="c1" (
    set arg=-t root@server1 ssh root@container1.lxc
) else (
    set arg=%*
    set icon=cmder_red.ico
)

"%cmderlocation%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.exe" -Single -run cmd /c "%cmderlocation%\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin\ssh.exe %arg%" -new_console:C:"%cmderlocation%\icons\%icon%" -new_console:P:^<Ubuntu^> -new_console:t:"%1"
```